# MonacaのCloudIDEでgithub連携をやろうとすると、初期化に失敗しましたと表示される

Tags: monaca

MonacaのCloudIDEを利用していますが、githubのプライベートリポジトリを接続しようとした所、初期化に失敗しましたと表示されました。

空っぽのRepositoryが必要なので、作りましたが、初期化すると反応しなくなるので使えませんでした。

どなたか試された方がいれば教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本件、Asial側と相談して不具合であることがわかりました。
すでに対応済みです。

また、それでも対応できない場合は、一度SourceをDLして、アップロードしなおして
空のリポジトリを作ると上手くいきます。